# How to get all `supports` attributes by post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

i.e. when post is registered, like this:

```
$args= [
  'supports' => ['thumbnail', 'title', 'post-formats'  ...]
]
```

If later, I want to get all `supports` attribute for specific post type, which function should I use?  i.e. something like `get_supports('post');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists the [`get_all_post_type_supports()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_all_post_type_supports/)  to get the supported features for a given post type. It's a wrapper for the `_wp_post_type_features` global variable:

```
/**
 * Get all the post type features
 *
 * @since 3.4.0
 *
 * @global array $_wp_post_type_features
 *
 * @param string $post_type The post type.
 * @return array Post type supports list.
 */
function get_all_post_type_supports( $post_type ) {
        global $_wp_post_type_features;

        if ( isset( $_wp_post_type_features[$post_type] ) )
                return $_wp_post_type_features[$post_type];

        return array();
}
```

### Example:

Here's an usage example from the wp shell for the `'post'` post type:

```
wp> print_r( get_all_post_type_supports( 'post' ) );
Array
(
    [title] => 1
    [editor] => 1
    [author] => 1
    [thumbnail] => 1
    [excerpt] => 1
    [trackbacks] => 1
    [custom-fields] => 1
    [comments] => 1
    [revisions] => 1
    [post-formats] => 1
)
```

Another useful wrapper is [`get_post_types_by_support()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_all_post_type_supports/).

Answer (score 0):

I've chosen to use `$GLOBALS['_wp_post_type_features']`, that returns like this:

```
Array
(
    [post] => Array
        (
            [title] => 1
            [editor] => 1
            [author] => 1
            [thumbnail] => 1
            [excerpt] => 1
            [trackbacks] => 1
            [custom-fields] => 1
            [comments] => 1
            [revisions] => 1
            [post-formats] => 1 
        )

    [page] => Array
        (
            [title] => 1
            [editor] => 1
            [author] => 1
            [thumbnail] => 1
            [page-attributes] => 1
            [custom-fields] => 1
            [comments] => 1
            [revisions] => 1
        )
 ...
```